# Algorithm to periodically call function if input is above threshold. Help needed

Tags: c, algorithm

Okay, so each second I read a value from an analog source to a variable.
I compare it to the previously measured value and if ifts above a certain threshold x I call a function (or do other stuff...).

Now my problem is: When the analog value changes only very slowly over time, and the difference between two measurements is never above the threshold, I will never call the function.

How about only set the variable for the previous value to the current value if I actually called the function? How would you solve the problem? Or what are your suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

This is basically my code:

```
void main()
{
 curVal = readAlgSrc();
 prevVal = curVal;

 while(1)
 {

   if(oneSecPassed()) curVal = readAlgSrc();

   if(abs(prevVal - curVal) > 4)
   {
     doStuff();
   }
   prevVal = curVal;

 }

}
```

Comment: This seems more like a question of defining the behavior you are trying to achieve, rather than a question of how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would work. I don't see why not.
If you want to catch a change of more than 4 in a single second, your current code does it.
If you want to catch a change of more than 4, no matter how long it takes, your suggested change should do it.

Notes:

1. It seems that all code should be under `if (oneSecPassed())`.
2. You seem to assume that the value never decreases. If it does, then your current code will do nothing if it changes from 100 to 0 and back up to 101. OK, if this is the behavior you want.